# difference between $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm struggling with $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.
We know that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$, but $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is countable and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. How two equal sets could be equal if one is countable when the other one isn't ?

edit 1: $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ the closure of ${\mathbb{Q}}$

edit 2: I am in the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ (with Dedekind complete field)

Comment: They can't; $\mathbb Q$ is countable, but perhaps $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (which you have not defined) is not

Comment: What is $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ here?

Comment: Ok, so the algebraic closure is uncountable, and because $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is an algebraic closure it is also uncountable ?

Comment: The use of "closure" and the notation $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ is ***very*** overloaded throughout mathematics. You need to specify *exactly* what kind of closure, if topological, then in what space, etc.

Comment: The field of algebraic numbers $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ is different from $\Bbb R$, since for example $\pi\not\in \overline{\Bbb Q}$.

Comment: @Dietrich: And also $i$ is algebraic and not a real number.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, neither $\Bbb R$ is contained in $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ nor $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ is contained in $\Bbb R$. But this is irrelevant. We just don't have $\overline{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R$.

Comment: The phrase "Dedekind complete field" added to the Question in connection with "I am in the construction of $\mathbb R$" suggests that Dedekind cuts are involved, which amounts to a *topological* rather than "algebraic closure".  It is worth clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a *regular* thing, in fact, it's quite *normal*. And much like those two terms the term "closure" and the notation $\overline A$ has plenty of meanings throughout mathematics.

1. In the topological space $\Bbb R$, the closure of the set $\Bbb Q$, which is often denoted by $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ is indeed $\Bbb R$. This is set of all the limit points of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$, and by the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ we get that $\overline{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R$.
2. In the topological space $\Bbb Q$, the closure of the set $\Bbb Q$ is just $\Bbb Q$ itself. Because given any space $X$, it is closed in itself, so its closure *with respect to itself* is itself again.
3. In the algebraic context, the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$, also sometimes denoted by $\overline{\Bbb Q}$, is the collection of all the *complex* numbers which are roots of polynomials with rational coefficients. This is not even a subset of $\Bbb R$, since $i^2=-1$, and so $i\in\overline{\Bbb Q}$, but $i$ is not a real number.
4. In a different algebraic context, one might want to look at the *real* closure of $\Bbb Q$, which is *not* usually denoted by $\overline{\Bbb Q}$, which is all the real numbers which are roots of polynomials with rational coefficients. This is of course a subset of $\Bbb R$, and in fact we can say more from a model theoretic point of view: it has the same first-order theory as the real numbers.

So we get four different closures. But exactly the first one is uncountable, and indeed $\Bbb R$, whereas the others are countable.

This is yet again a testament to the importance of context. When I tell you that we need to talk about Kevin, your first question would *normally* be "who's Kevin? I don't know you sir." or "Which Kevin?". Because maybe I want to talk about award winning actor Kevin Costner, or maybe I want to talk about award winning writer-director Kevin Smith, or maybe your best friend is Kevin and I want to talk about him. ***Context!***

Answer (score 4):

Your edit remains unclear, and your comment does not particularly help. The problem is that the "closure" means different things in different settings.

The notation $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ can be used for either the *topological closure* of $\mathbb Q$ inside some larger topological space such as $\mathbb R$, or for the *algebraic closure* of $\mathbb Q$.

If you use it to mean the *topological closure* inside $\mathbb R$ then $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ is equal to $\mathbb R$ (as the answer of @Mark says), and it is uncountable.

If you use it to mean the *algebraic closure* then this is really a topic in number theory or abstract algebra, where $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ is used (sometimes... usually...) to refer to all complex numbers $z \in \mathbb C$ which are roots of polynomial equations with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$. In this case $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ is a **countable** subset of $\mathbb C$. The proof of countability is that there are only countable many polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$, and each has only finitely many solutions in $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 3):

$\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is not $\mathbb{Q}$ itself, it is its closure. These are two completely different things. The closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}$ which are the limit of some sequence of elements from $\mathbb{Q}$. And yes, it is equal to $\mathbb{R}$.